# Python - Read_csv read length of column

Tags: python, csv

I am using read_csv to load a column from a csv file into my code. It is a large file and takes about 45seconds to load this column.
Instead of loading this entire column, is it possible to read just the last element of this column?
I am not even interested in the value of the last element, but I am interested in the index of the last element. In other words, is it possible to determine the length of a column - without needing to load the entire column?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get last index of row, follow this code snippet:

```py
    fname = "test.csv"

    count = 0

    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            count += 1

    print("Total number of lines is:", count)
```

If you want to total column number, follow this:

```py
    df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", nrows=1)

    print("total col number:", len(df.columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

try with dask or csv libraries, they are way faster and should be enough for your requirements. more info [here](https://medium.com/casual-inference/the-most-time-efficient-ways-to-import-csv-data-in-python-cc159b44063d)